# How do I use a ViewPager with the AHBottomNavigation bar?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigationbar

I want to use the ViewPager with the BottomNavigation bar from Aurel Hubert https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation

I have following code:

My activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.aaron.waller.mrpolitik.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/content_id">

    <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
        android:id="@+id/myBottomNavigation_ID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AHBottomNavigation.OnTabSelectedListener {

    AHBottomNavigation bottomNavigation;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();




        bottomNavigation = (AHBottomNavigation) findViewById(R.id.myBottomNavigation_ID);
        bottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
        bottomNavigation.setDefaultBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        this.createNavItems();

    }


    //Create items, add them to bar, set propertied and set current item
    private void createNavItems() {
        //CREATE ITEMS
        AHBottomNavigationItem ohnemundItem = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Parteien", R.drawable.parteienicon);
        AHBottomNavigationItem grinseItem = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Statistiken", R.drawable.statsicon);
        AHBottomNavigationItem lachItem = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Fragen", R.drawable.fragenicon);

        //ADD THEM to bar
        bottomNavigation.addItem(ohnemundItem);
        bottomNavigation.addItem(grinseItem);
        bottomNavigation.addItem(lachItem);


        //set properties
        bottomNavigation.setDefaultBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEFEFE"));

        //set current item
        bottomNavigation.setCurrentItem(0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(int position, boolean wasSelected) {
        if (position == 0) {
            ParteienFragment parteienFragment = new ParteienFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_id, parteienFragment).commit();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            StatistikenFragment statistikenFragment = new StatistikenFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_id, statistikenFragment).commit();
        } else if (position == 2) {
            FragenFragment fragenFragment = new FragenFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_id, fragenFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I have no clue how to implement a ViewPager in this case.
I have already googled but have found nothing specific to this NavigationBar.
Is it possible at all to add a swipe effect with this navigation bar?
All I want is that I can wipe left and right between my Fragments.

Comment: What's with you?

Comment: Using a ViewPager with BottomNavigation goes against Material Design - https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior

Comment: @Joy What do you mean? What is wrong with my question? Please explain, i'm new to Android Studio

Comment: @michaelcarrano but how can I achive it then?

Comment: What's   output display after run code?

Comment: @Joy I dont have any errors. I only want that I can swipe with my fingers between my Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late but here goes a way of achieving what you pretend. If you want a swipe behaviour you should make a touch event in your activity to detect a swipe. After you detect a swipe it should be simple, just get the current item, and depending on the swipe set the position on the bottom navigation.

Example:

```
if(isSwipeRight && bottomNavigation.getCurrentItem() > 0)
    bottomNavigation.setCurrentItem(bottomNavigation.getCurrentItem()-1);
else if(isSwipeLeft && bottomNavigation.getCurrentItem() < numTabs-1)
    bottomNavigation.setCurrentItem(bottomNavigation.getCurrentItem()+1);
```

Comment: I don't think it's what the questioner want. I think he wants the appearance of default ViewPager. Does your code just make a slide even if the user doesn't swipe totally?